# Bar graph for binary variable across two groups?

Tags: r, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have the following data (sample below):

```
Participant Group  Choice
1           Control     0
2           Control     0
3           Control     0
4           Stress      1
5           Stress      1
6           Stress      1
```

I want to create a bar graph depicting the frequencies of Choice (0 or 1) for Group (Stress VS Control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `table` and use `barplot` which comes with R.

```
barplot(with(dat, table(Choice, Group)), main="My plot", beside=T, col=2:3)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

(Forgive me that I chose slightly more interesting data :)

```
dat <- structure(list(Participant = 1:6, Group = c("Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Stress", "Stress", "Stress"), Choice = c(0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` to count the frequencies, convert the variables to factor and plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(Group, Choice) %>%
  mutate(Choice = factor(Choice), Group = factor(Group)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Group, n, fill = Choice) + geom_col()
```

Comment: thanks- my Group variable is actually already defined as a factor. How do I modify the code for that?

Comment: You can remove the line `Group = factor(Group)` from `mutate`.

Comment: Error in count(., Group, Info_ChoiceR) : object 'Group' not found

Comment: @Chester Is your column called `Group` ? Can you run the above code as it is. Does that work?

Comment: no, I am having trouble with the whole code unfortunately. The variables worked in my regression but are not working for plotting.